# Silverlight control's name isn't available in code-behind

Tags: silverlight-4.0, contextmenu, code-behind

I have the following XAML:

```
<controls:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
         <controls:ContextMenu Height="Auto" x:Name="contextMenu">
                   <controls:MenuItem x:Name="AddMenuItem" Header="Add document" 
                                      IsEnabled="True" Click="AddMenuItem_Click">
                   </controls:MenuItem>
            ...
```

And I cannot see the contextMenu in code-behind (Compiling error "The name "contextMenu" doesn't exist in the current context"). 
I've tried to find it:

```
ContextMenu menu = FindName("contextMenu") as ContextMenu;
```

but it always returns null.

I've checked the build action - it is set to Page.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the `ContextMenuService` to get the ContextMenu of an object. The ContextMenuService provides the method `GetContextMenu(DependencyObject)` that returns the ContextMenu of the specified object.

So in your case you need to write:

```
DependencyObject objectWithContextMenu = // Control that has a ContextMenu
ContextMenu menu = ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(objectWithContextMenu);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, control that has a ContextMenu is unavailable in code-behind too